# Running JavaScript in PHP file

Tags: php, javascript

I made a simple login using JavaScript, but record the username in a PHP session.It's a simple web chat, so I want when the chat page is loaded the user to be forced to pick an username, but after that I want to store that info ina a PHP session and if the page is reloaded for some reason to do a check if $_SESSION['UserName'] is empty and if it's not to stop the script from executing again.I put my login JS in `<body onload..>` and the code looks like this:

```
<body onload = "showUser(), showChat(), <?php if ($_SESSION['UserName']==""){
{
  Login();
}?>">
```

I'm just learning now, so I gues I have some newb mistakes, like I'm almost sure that I'm not calling the `Login()` function right (it's JS function), but that's my strating point.Could anyone explain to me, how should I do the check properly and add the JS function in my PHP code?

P.S And I don't know if this really matter but if I remove the PHP code and leave liek this:

```
<body onload = "showUser(), showChat(),Login()">
```

My script is executed properly and I get everything that should be shown when the page is loaded, but when I add the PHP script and try to load the page I get blank page.I really wonder what's the reason for this too?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_Javascript - please read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply call this as:

```
<?php 
    if($_SESSION['UserName'] == ""){ 
?>
<body onload="showUser(), showChat()">
<?php
    }
    else
    {
?>
<body onload="showUser(), showChat(), Login();">
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\Program Files\webPHP\xampp\htdocs\MyChat\chat1.php on line 75

Comment: Ops, sry, I've been trying some other thing, could you post the entire code again?Thanks

Comment: U can simply call this as 

    <?php 
        if($_SESSION['UserName'] == ""){ 
?>
    <body onload="showUser(), showChat()">
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
    <body onload="showUser(), showChat(), Login();">
    <?php
    }
    ?>

Answer (score 4):

You cant call a js function from php. instead we have to print the js function as string in php so it will be executed as js along the html.

```
<body onload = "showUser(); showChat(); <?php if ($_SESSION['UserName']==""){ echo 'Login();'; }?>">
```

**To Write efficient php code:**

```
<body onload = "showUser(); showChat(); <?php echo (($_SESSION['UserName']=='')?'Login();':''); ?>">
```

You get blank page because of fatal error. which is occurred due to the javascript function you called in php (ERROR: Undefined function login() ).

Answer (score 2):

You must echo the text `Login();` from PHP - PHP does not execute Javascript, but you can use it to control which Javascript functions are called.

```
<body onload="showUser(), showChat(), <?php 
    if(isset(!$_SESSION['UserName']) || $_SESSION['UserName'] == ""){ 
        echo 'Login();';
     }?>">
```

You are effectively using PHP to create two different body tags - one for logged in users, and one for others.

**Side note**: it's good practice to check that an array item exists before attempting to access it: `isset($_SESSION['UserName']) || $_SESSION['UserName']` checks first if `$_SESSION['UserName']` has been set, then checks if it has been set to something other than an empty string.

Comment: Thanks all try it now, just to make it clear, I put all the info in DB, which i proseed in another .PHP file and if the user dosen't provide any text I just assign 'anonymos' to $_SESSION['UserName']

Comment: if we check isset in this case, it alows the logged in users inside the condition. use ! before isset to reverse the function.

Comment: Now I see how to add my JS in PHP script, but still can't prevent the Login() function from executin when the page is reloaded

Comment: @Leron, add the ! before the first `$_SESSION`, I had accidentally missed it out, sorry!